# Webpage Not Showing All the HTML Elements

Tags: html, css, web

I am learning HTML,CSS and JAVAScript and I recently wrote a very simple code. It showed everything and was working fine until I added the div class "mainLeft". After that it doesn't show anything except for the code before that class. Can you kindly assist? 
Below is the HTML and CSS code;

**CSS Code**

```css
**CSS Code** 
    body {
      background-color: white;
    }
    .main h1 {
      font-family: Candara;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    .main {
      display: table;
      height: 50px;
      width: 600px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background-color: #13b5ea;
    }
    .SME {
      display: table;
      position: absolute;
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      margin-left: -125px;
      margin-top: -125px;
      color: #13b5ea;
    }
    .SME h4 {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: white;
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-family: Candara;
    }
    .DataAnalysis {
      display: table;
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      left: 38.3%;
      top: 28%;
      margin-left: -100px;
      margin-top: -100px;
      color: #13b5ea;
    }
    .DataAnalysis h4 {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: white;
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-family: Candara;
    }
    .ProdMonitor {
      display: table;
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      left: 38.3%;
      top: 72%;
      margin-left: -100px;
      margin-top: -100px;
      color: #13b5ea;
    }
    .ProdMonitor h4 {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: white;
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-family: Candara;
    }
    .mainLeft h1 {
      font-family: Candara;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    .mainLeft {
      display: table;
      height: 50px;
      width: 600px;
      margin-right: auto;
      background-color: #13b5ea;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="satmap.css" />
  <title>My Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Go bananas!-->
  <div class="main">
    <h1> XYZ</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="mainLeft">
    <h1> Current Stats </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="SME">
    <h4> My Explorer </h4>
  </div>

  <div class="DataAnalysis">
    <h4> Data Analysis </h4>
  </div>

  <div class="ProdMonitor">
    <h4> Production Monitoring </h4>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'd recommend not using `position:absolute` everywhere.

Comment: your code seems to work, although not sure what you are trying to do. see the snippet i made of your code.

Comment: If you do not use color:white for your Hs you will see the text show http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/p42boov2/

Comment: But you can see that i made blue squares for all the divs. Even if i change the Hs color, it doesn't show the squares.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I don't see any div with the class 'mainLeft'. You only have texts in those divs so the reason you can't see anything is because you have this css on your h definitions.

```
color: white;
```

Comment: It is the second div from the top. What do you mean by nothing in the divS. There are Hs in the divs and CSS in the file below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Everyone. I solved it.
I had forgottent to add **background-color** attribute in CSS.